# Ember js, load additional Model in nested resource

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I got completely stuck, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drulia/efmAn/). In the example I want to be able to load additional data when i visit url /cars/details, but I can't figure out how can I do that.

here is my models:

```
App.Cars = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    details: DS.belongsTo('App.Details')
});

App.Details = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    color: DS.attr('string'),
    wheels: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And here shortened FIXTURES

```
App.Cars.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alfa Romeo',
  details: 1
}];

App.Details.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alfa Romeo',
  color: 'Red',
  wheels: '14'
}];
```

Any ideas how to make that happen, I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, just don't know what.

**Edit**

the interesting thing is, that on original project if I reload on a url which suppose to show details, I see the details, but that's happens only once. I printed the model to console:

```
App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(params) // prints once only if loaded app was loaded to this url
    return App.Details.find(params.table_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    console.log(model) // prints every time you click on a car
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that make your code not working:

You are passing the `car` to the `{{linkTo 'details' car}}` helper.
Consequently, the `car` will be the model of the `DetailsRoute` (and the `DetailsController` too), but you want the `car.details` instead:

```
{{#each car in controller}}
    {{#linkTo 'details' car.details}}
        {{car.name}}
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

The other thing that does not work is that your fixtures `id` are integers.

Replace them by a string and it will work, as [you can see in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/efmAn/9/).

Comment: Any ideas why this would show `undefined` in the link once I start use real data instead of FIXTURES? I looked through all data and it is exactly the same as FIXTURES, and I can show on screen anything from Cars.Model except details, though when I use FIXTURES I can even show car.details on screen and it shows ember model code.

Comment: @Giedrius this is a little bit hard to find where the problem comes from. Maybe you can ask a new question with the detail of the requests sent to the server, the response,...